# Spring boot JPA null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am developing an JavaFx application with spring boot,JPA, and H2. I have a user entity when I try to add a new user into the DB it throws NPE in the controller on the button's click action. As it is seen I use only autowire notation. I researched 
but findings did not help out. Any help please?

```
package com.core;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(SharedSpringConfiguration.class)
public class Runner extends Application {

   private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);        
   }

   @Override
   public void init() {
    context = SpringApplication.run(Runner.class);
   }
}
```

```
package com.dao;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long ID;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userPass;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(long ID, String userName, String userPass) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPass = userPass;
    }
}
```

```
package com.service;

@Service
public class UserService {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   public UserService() {
   }

   public void saveUser(User user) {
     userRepository.save(user);
   }
}
```

```
package com.repository;
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

```
package com.controller

@Controller
public class MethodController implements Initializable {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @FXML
  void methodSave(MouseEvent event) {
    userService.saveUser(new User(11, "TestUser", "noPass")); //Throws NPE. Indicates that userService is null. But I autowire the userService.
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `UserService` class you try and autowire `UserRepository`. `UserRepository` is not setup to be a spring component. Try adding `@Repository` to your `UserRepository` class.

Comment: @gonzo, I already tried that. It does not help

Comment: Which `@Repository` tag did you try? You won't be able to autowire `UserRepository` without it being scanned by spring.

Comment: @gonzo, org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

Comment: @gonzo an @Repository annotation is not necessary. It is inherited from the `CrudRepository`

Comment: I have the same problem. @Matahari, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's in `SharedSpringConfiguration`, but you probably need `@EnableJpaRepositories` on one of your configuration classes. `@Repository` on the CrudRepo should be unnecessary.

Comment: thank you for bringing it up. My bad I made an implementation mistake in SharedConfig... Now the question what is the way to use the UserService service = Runner.context.getBean(UserService.class); in my controller. I mean how to define it? like make the context as public static in the Runner and reach it from any controller or what is the way that it should be done?

Comment: After probing we can accomplish it via ApplicationContextProvider

Answer (score 0):

Change your SpringBootApplication package from `com.core` to `com`

because SpringBootApplication by default will scan only that packages and sub packages.

else

add `@ComponentScan` annotation in SpringBootApplication and scan the packages.